# Kendo PagerInput input becomes enabled again after content loaded

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am having a very hard time figuring out how to ensure that my NumericInput component is disabled once my other tab (which is the same component, just different data) loads up. This shouldn't be hard, but for some reason it is. So my issue is that:

- On first load, my first tab has the numeric input disabled. Good
- I switch over to my other tab, and the numeric input is not disabled. Bad, should be disabled.

[image]

- If I go back to the first tab, then to the second tab, then that input is actually disabled.

[image]

The way I went about implementing this is via a directive. The reason for this is that looking at their documentation, it does not appear that the `kendo-pager-input` component has an exposed `disabled` property. Also setting a `[disabled]="true"` on it does nothing anyway.

My HTML code in question where the pager is called:

```
<ng-template kendoPagerTemplate let-totalPages="totalPages" let-currentPage="currentPage">
      <div>
        <kendo-pager-info></kendo-pager-info>
      </div>
      <div class="pagerMiddleItems">
        <kendo-pager-prev-buttons></kendo-pager-prev-buttons>
        <kendo-pager-input kendoPagerDisableInput></kendo-pager-input>
        <kendo-pager-next-buttons [disabled]="loading"></kendo-pager-next-buttons>
      </div>
      <kendo-pager-page-sizes [pageSizes]="pagesizes" cy-data="pageSize"></kendo-pager-page-sizes>
    </ng-template>
```

The directive:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";
import { PagerInputComponent } from "@progress/kendo-angular-grid";

@Directive({
    selector: '[kendoPagerDisableInput]'
})
export class KendoPagerDisableInputDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(
        private ref : ElementRef,
        private rn : Renderer2,
        private pager: PagerInputComponent
    ) {

    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.disableInput();
    }

    private disableInput() {
        
        if(this.ref && this.ref.nativeElement !== undefined) {
            if(this.pager.numericInput) {
                let input = this.pager.numericInput.numericInput.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
                input.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: made this stackblitz, but oddly my directive there does not work at all (whereas at least locally it worked on the first tab. I am sure there are some things missing, but this is an MVP of the problem). However the input is marked as disabled. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqa1bx

Comment: I will try to create one today, time permitting.

Comment: @SomeStudent - Are you using the Kendo UI for Angular TabStrip component or something else (like Material)?

Comment: I do not think so, @David. This pagination lives within a kendo-grid

Comment: "NumericInput component is disabled once my other tab" what are you using to separate the grids between different tabs?

Comment: @David, the kendo-grid lives inside of a mat-tab group

Comment: @SomeStudent - That is what I was afraid of. Kendo and Material do not mix and match well. I had something similar on one of my old projects where I had to setup a view child on the Kendo grid, handle the MatTabChangeEvent of the Material tab, and then manually refresh the Kendo grid.